# Post formats for Pages not saving

Tags: post-formats

I have enabled Post Formats for Pages on my WordPress site but when I update the Page the format reverts back to Standard.

Here is what I added to my functions.php file to enable Post Formats:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'link' ) );

add_post_type_support( 'page', 'post-formats' );
```

Comment: Looks like this is due to new block editor. When Classic Editor plugin is activated, code is working as expected. You want to report issue in Gutenberg plugin.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing still in WordPress 5.4.1.  Has there been an updates or a trac bug reported?